# Difference between Time.new(year, month, day) and Time.local(year, month, day) in ruby

Tags: ruby

I see that Time class has different methods to instanciate a new Time object, what's the difference between calling Time.new or .local or mktime ??

Share they the same implementation under different names?

I see in Ruby documentation for Time that constructor method new is represented with optional parameters set to nil by default 
other methods like .local and mktime have an overload for every different sign
is this only because you can't have overloads for constructor in Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

`Time.mktime` is a synonym for `Time.local` and creates the time based on the values you give it. `Time.new` uses the time values from the system to create the object.

I found [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_time.html) to be quite useful:

> Time.new -> aTime Returns a Time object initialized to the current
>   system time. Note: The object created will be created using the
>   resolution available on your system clock, and so may include
>   fractional seconds.
>
> Time.gm( year [, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec] ) -> aTime 
>   Time.gm( sec, min, hour, day, month, year, wday, yday, isdst, tz ) ->
>   aTime Creates a time based on given values, interpreted as UTC (GMT).
>   The year must be specified. Other values default to the minimum value
>   for that field (and may be nil or omitted). Months may be specified by
>   numbers from 1 to 12, or by the three-letter English month names.
>   Hours are specified on a 24-hour clock (0..23). Raises an
>   ArgumentError if any values are out of range. Will also accept ten
>   arguments in the order output by Time#to_a .
>   Time.local( year [, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec] ) -> aTime 
>   Time.local( sec, min, hour, day, month, year, wday, yday, isdst, tz )
>   -> aTime Same as Time.gm , but interprets the values in the local time zone.
>
> Time.mktime( year, month, day, hour, min, sec, usec ) -> aTime Synonym
>   for Time.local .